# Can a function return a pointer to an array of variable length arrays?

Tags: c, c99

I tried to define the transpose of a square matrix but I'm hung up on the function's type signature. I'm trying to generalize from this (which works):

```
float (*matrix_transpose (float matrix[4][4]))[4];
```

To this (which doesn't):

```
float (*matrix_transpose (int n, float matrix[n][n]))[n];
```

GCC says this:

```
error: 'n' undeclared here (not in a function)
 float (*matrix_transpose (int n, float matrix[n][n]))[n];
                                                       ^
```

Is there a correct way or write what I want or is it perhaps not possible in the language, or a standards oversight, or a GCC bug?

Comment: Yes, just remove the last `n`. VLA dimensions aren't checked at compile time anyway so you aren't losing any safety (i.e. it was somewhat unsafe with to begin with)

Comment: @M.M How could they "not be checked at compile time"? The compiler needs to know the size to compute (or emit code that computes) the addresses of the elements!

Comment: @immibis `n` might not be known at compile-time anyway, obviously it cannot be checked. The size computation you mention occurs at runtime. `n` could be resulting from user input.  example , `float (*p)[m] = matrix_transpose(3, mat);`  - this is correct if and only if `m == 3` but this can't be checked at compile-time because `m` is not known. It just causes silent UB if `m` does not happen to be `3` when executed.

Comment: immibis is saying that if I had e.g. (matrix_transpose(2, (float[2][2]){{1,2}{3,4}}))[1][0], the compiler needs to know how much to offset to multiply by 1. It needs to know the size of the minor array dimension.

Comment: The return type is in fact a pointer to a variable length array, not a pointer to an array of VLAs. The latter would be `float (*foo(float input[4][4]))[4][n];`. Note that in that case you have to either use a constant expression or a global variable for the non-VLA array size.